# context menu is not display in web project in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

context menu is working well in desktop project but not display in web project...........kindly help and suggest if anyone has some suitable answer

Answer (score 3):

**In `main.mxml`, on application initialize, run this function:**

```
private function init():void {

   var customMenuItem1:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem(“WHATEVER DUDE”);

   var contextMenuCustomItems:Array = application.contextMenu.customItems;

   contextMenuCustomItems.push(customMenuItem1);

}
```